# In Drupal 6 how to show field other than title field in select list of related content types

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

I have two content types Institute and Faculties. The title of the Institute content type is Unique Institute Number. This content type also contains Institute Name field. In the Faculty content type I want users to select the Institute Name from a select list. With Node Reference I can show the Title of the Institute Content Type in the select list but Institute Number is not a comprehensible Information list. How can I show the Institute Names in the select list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, using the titles of the selectable nodes is just the default behavior - you can change this by using a Views module view. On the Node Reference fields configuration form, there should be an 'advanced' section where you can select a view as the source for the select functionality.